# Connection refused in rest assured for HTTPS request

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I am trying to test a REST API having an ELB similar to below:
https://systemtest-inventory.com/v1/inventory/getInventory

When I tried the URL with postman chrome, it is giving me valid response. 
But when I try to use it in Java program as below:

```
RestAssured.baseURI="https://systemtest-inventory.com/";
        RestAssured.get("v1/inventory/getInventory").then().assertThat().contentType(ContentType.JSON);
```

It gives this error:

> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to
>   https://systemtest-inventory.com refused

I am aware that I am using HTTPS and need to have security certificate trusted. However, I am not sure how to do it. Is there any way in Rest assured to test with HTTPS and not HTTP.

Comment: isn't that host down right now?

Comment: @Divers: Of course host is running as in parallel I am getting correct response.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something as below for ignoring HTTPS Validation:

```
given().config(RestAssured.config().sslConfig( new SSLConfig().relaxedHTTPSValidation());
```

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the HTTPS Connection you can use:

```
RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
```